# Pandas Ignore Non-Date Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column containing a few non-date values but mostly dates.... The non-date values are either blank or '???' strings. I am trying to find the difference between today's date and the listed date but I am getting the following error. How would I adjust this to ignore the non-date values?

Error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Code:

```
today_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
bridge['Days'] = bridge['First Date'].dt.date - today_date
bridge['Days'] = bridge['Days'].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us convert to date first

```
bridge['First Date'] = pd.to_datetime(bridge['First Date'], errors = 'coerce')
```